# Ошибки в лексике

Tags: лексика

Задание 2. В следующих предложениях исправьте ошибки, связанные с не-правильным употреблением фразеологизмов и устойчивых сочетаний. Объясните, в чем они заключаются.
1. Бригадир не уверял собрание, что сделает все по силе возможности, одна-ко порядки остались прежними. 2. Решение в крайней мере заставит некоторых за-думаться. 
Задание 3. В следующих предложениях устраните речевую избыточность и определите ее тип. 
1. Они сохранились в целости и сохранности. 2. Суп дня или са¬лат здесь ка-ждый день разные. 
Задание 4. Отметьте лексические и фразеологические сред¬ства, нарушаю-щие стилевую однородность предложения; исправьте предложение.
В це¬лях рационального использования поливной воды в вегетацион¬ный пе-риод вводится водооборот между колхозами.

Answer (score 1):

Задание 2. 1. Исправленный вариант: *Бригадир не уверял собрание, что сделает все по мере возможности, однако порядки остались прежними.* **Ошибка**: контаминация (смешение) фразеологизмов ***по мере сил*** и ***по мере возможности***.

2. Исправленный вариант:  *Решение по крайней мере заставит некоторых задуматься.* **Ошибка**: употребление фразеологизма ***по крайней мере* с предлогом *в*.** (Возможно, здесь имеет место контаминация фразеологизмов *в крайнем случае* и *по крайней мере*.)

Задание 3. Исправленный вариант: 1. *Они сохранились в целости.* **Ошибка**: ***сохранились в сохранности*** - тавтология.

2. Исправленный вариант: *Суп или салат здесь каждый день разные.* **Ошибка**: **суп *дня*... каждый *день*** - тавтология.

Задание 4. Исправленный вариант: *В целях рационального использования поливной воды в вегетационный период применяется система водооборота между колхозами.* ***Ошибка***: *вводится водооборот*. Водооборот не вводится, а используется или *применяется*.

Comment: Задание 2. 1 - неверно ответили, по-моему.  Устойчивые сочетания "сделать по возможности" или "в силе", но не "по силе возможности".

Comment: Я сам удивлён тем, что в сетевых словарях ЕСТЬ выражение "по силе возможности".

Comment: Может быть, они путают это с выражением "по ***мере*** возможности".

Comment: Наверное, "по силе возможности" устарело.

Comment: В последнем, по-моему, тоже немножко не в тему.  Что, если канцелярский стиль и задумывался? Тогда нарушения нет.  Но вот "водооборот между" - не бывает.  "Между", по-моему, может быть только "водообмен" или "обмен водой между"...

Comment: Там речь о стилевой однородности. Водооборот стилевую однородность, вроде, не нарушает.

Comment: Ну, хорошо. Тогда какой Вы видете "стиль" в остальной части этого предложения, чтобы "канцелярский" нарушал бы его [однородность]?

Comment: Я об этом тоже думал, всё предложение  в стиле документа выдержано. Видимо, я не нашел ошибку.

Comment: Может быть, "вводится процедура балансирования водорасхода среди колхозов"?  Я не уверен, что такое "водооборот" в применении к колхозам (или вообще).  Есть "круговорот воды в природе", есть "товарооборот", а "**водо**оборот"...

Comment: http://www.hydroaudit.ru/vodooborot - это о водообороте

Comment: Ну, тогда-таки не "вводится водооборот между колхозами"...  Это ведь "системы водооборота", и они не "вводятся", а "применяются", то есть, строятся очистные сооружения и т.д.

Comment: Ок, оставляю прежний официальный стиль, и вместо "вводится пишу" "применяется система водооборота".